# WAKE ON LAN works on one network adaptor, but not the other. both Realtek

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

Wake on LAN

I have a problem. I use LogMeIn wake up feature on my PC.

However, I cannot get the Wake-on-LAN feature to work. I have enabled it in the BIOS and enabled it on the adapter in device manager. I currently have my PC programmed in the BIOS to wake up each morning and that works no problem.

I do have another adapter in the PC and wake on LAN works fine with it for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: We need specific information about the network adapaters in order to research if both of them even support this feature. Have you enabled the feature from within Windows for both devices? Only the the device on the motherboard itself would be enabled by the BIOS setting. Why do you have two lan networks adaptors?  Most systems only require one.

Answer (score 0):

For Intel NICs, you have to enable Power Management Event(s) [PME], which is a separate setting from enabling WOL. Realtek NICs might have the same requirements. See if your NIC has a setting, in Device Manager, relating to PME, and verify that it is enabled.